# Which is correct or natural, "over a range" or "within a range"?

Tags: prepositions

I created the following sentences:

> 1. The room temperature can be adjusted **within** a range set by the room owner.
> 2. The room temperature can be adjusted **over** a range set by the room owner.

According to a result of Google search I made, it seems that natives use the second one more frequently. However, I am afraid that "over" may be misinterpreted as "beyond".

Comment: You cannot rely upon mere frequency when two phrases have different meanings.  **under the chair** is probably less frequent than **on the chair** but frequency is meaningless there.

Answer (score 1):

**over** can be used in this context, but in my (UK English) opinion it is, as you suggest, misleading. The Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries have a definition of over as **above**, which would mean above the maximum value of the range. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over) also suggests that it can also mean **within** a range:

> 4. b
>
> (1): all through or throughout
>   - showed me over the house
>   - went over his notes
>
> (2): used as a function word connecting one mathematical set and another whose > elements are coefficients or values of parameters used to form elements of the > first set
>    - polynomials over the field of real numbers

Meaning 1 suggests a very systematic coverage of the range: this doesn't fit with **can be** in your sentence. Meaning 2 is a bit technical.

Looking at actual usages, this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adjusted%20over%20the%20range%2Cadjusted%20within%20the%20range&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadjusted%20over%20the%20range%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadjusted%20within%20the%20range%3B%2Cc0) shows that **adjusted within the range** is marginally more popular, and the majority of usages of **adjusted over the range** are from technical documents, for example:

> ... an Atomika ion source and electronically processed into pulses 10-500 ns long by two sets of electrostatic deflection plates and four apertures (which can be adjusted **over the range** 0.125-4 mm diameter). *[Ferroelectric thin films](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=2lg5cLWbXIQC&pg=PA414&dq=%22adjusted%20over%20the%20range%22&hl=id&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL17rdz4_gAhVaeH0KHafDB8AQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22adjusted%20over%20the%20range%22&f=false)*

The number of usages is quite small, but it seems to me that **over** is somewhat more widely used with this meaning in US English than in UK english. This opinion is supported by the inclusion of a relevant definition in Merriam-Webster but not in the Oxford or Cambridge dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **over a range** refers to a *traversal* of the range.

The phrase **within a range** refers to the range as *boundary*.

In your context, the temperature has an upper and a lower limit, and the verb **set** refers to fixing the temperature somewhere within those boundaries, not to traversing the range, so **within** is more appropriate.

> We analyzed the espresso extraction over a range of temperatures.

There, the implication is that they examined the extraction at *various* temperatures, say 195°F, 198°F, 200°F, and 202°F.